# Detecting repetition of part of received data

Tags: c#, string

Based on the code shown.. Am I writing the right coding if i want to compare the data that were being stream in? Basically starting from the part

```
while(serialPort1.IsOpen)
```

For instance first string of data received was *T   12   29.5* then next string was *T  12  29.5* followed by *T  20  24.5* and on so.. basically unpredictable what going to be received next.

I want to program to be able to detect/count the number of appearance for the middle value..like...

====================
[number] | [Repeated times]

12        | 2

=================== but when another different number received,

[number] | [Repeated]

20 | 1

=================== the counter for the number will be overwrite and reset whenever a different number was received.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();

        string[] split = RxString.Split('.');  
        string dp = split[1];  
        Char c = dp[0]; 
        split[1] = c.ToString();
        RxString = split[0] + "." + split[1];  

        while (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
        string[] number = RxString.Split(' ');  
        string unit = number[1];  

        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < unit.Count(); i++) 
        {
        if(unit[i-1] == unit[i])
            count++;
        else
            count = 1;

        if(count == 4)
        {
    //execute some parameters
        }
        }
        }

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

        StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\acer\Documents\Data3.txt", true);  
        MyStreamWriter.Write(time + "      " + RxString + "\r\n");  
        MyStreamWriter.Flush();
        MyStreamWriter.Close();
    }
```

**EDIT V2**

Why wont the prog record data which only has count of 1?

```
            string[] number = RxString.Split(' ');  //split RxString by ' '
            string unit = number[1];  //unit = unit no. 
            int count = 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < unit.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (unit[i - 1] == unit[i])
                    count++;
                else
                {
                    count = 1;
                    StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\acer\Documents\Data3.txt", true);  //True tell SW to append to file instead of overwriting
                    MyStreamWriter.Write(time + "      " + RxString + "\r\n");  //Write time + string
                    MyStreamWriter.Flush();
                    MyStreamWriter.Close();
                }
```

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting ? Do you want the number to be overwrite and reset the counter or do you want to store the new number with its appropriate occurences ?

Comment: @Cubi if the count = 4, i will edit the time of these 4 data then record in DB. If the count != 4, those record will just be record in DB as usual

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. It seems that you already know what you're doing. What help do you need? Is it help with Sql part or what ?

Comment: @Fabjan Apart from checking for error, I'm also looking for better suggestion in coding for detecting the repetition..

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary to store each element and its own count :

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int?>();

while (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    string[] number = RxString.Split(' ');
    string unit = number[1];

    if (dict.ContainsKey(unit))
    {
        if (dict[unit].HasValue)
        {
            dict[unit]++;
            if (dict[unit] == 4)
            {
                // execute some parameters

                dict[unit] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(unit, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain what does the line "dict.Add(unit, 1) " does?

Comment: It adds to the dictionary a new key which is your unit variable and initializes the count to 1

Comment: What if I only want to let count be a temporary variable? As it will be "useless" after I executed some parameter once detected about the 4 counts..

Comment: You should flag it as "useless" for example by using a nullable int for the counter and set it to null when you don't need it anymore. I edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Imho nullable int doesn't make much sense here. It's just encapsulates int. Just remove Key/Value pair entry from dictionary if you don't need it. dict.Remove(unit); This collection will be collected by garbage collector when method end its work anyway

Comment: If you remove the key you'll loose the information you need as you are not able to know if the function has been executed for this particular key or not.

Comment: I mean remove it when it's not needed

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a special struct for that:

```
struct DataInfo
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }        
    ... Other data you require to work with
}
```

And use either `List<DataInfo>` or `Dictionary<string, DataInfo>` to store values;